# Regular Expression to check max of 2 digits,max of 4 alphabets in a alphanumeric string of length 6?

Tags: .net, regex

It should match all the following examples.

```
aBCd22
a2b2CD
22aBcD
```

Comment: Is the "max of" redundant? Should it be exactly 2 digits, and exactly 4 letters?

Comment: well not more 2 digits and not more than 4 alphabets

Comment: So something like "a2" or "" would match?

Comment: nope, the length of the string should be 6 ,i have given the examples it should match those.

Comment: well, it should match these examples aBCd22 a2b2CD 22aBcD abcd22

Comment: so the requirements are 'exactly' 2 digits and 4 characters, no more no less, as Zach Scrivena suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A compact version, using the **positive lookahead** operator:

```
^(?=(.*[0-9]){2})(?=(.*[A-Za-z]){4})[A-Za-z0-9]{6}$
```

Explanation:

```
(?=(.*[0-9]){2}) # asserts that you have 2 digits
(?=(.*[A-Za-z]){4}) # asserts that you have 4 characters
[A-Za-z0-9]{6} # does the actual matching of exactly 6 alphanumeric characters
```

A simple test case, in Python:

```
import re
rex = re.compile('(?=(.*[0-9]){2})(?=(.*[A-Za-z]){4})[A-Za-z0-9]{6}')
tests = ['aBCd22', 'a2b2CD', '22aBcD', 'asd2as', '', '201ABC', 'abcA213']
for test in tests:
print "'%s' %s" % 
       (test, "matched" if rex.match(test) != None else "didn't match")
```

Output:

```
'aBCd22' matched
'a2b2CD' matched
'22aBcD' matched
'asdas' didn't match
'' didn't match
'201ABC' didn't match
'abcA213' didn't match
```

Comment: Clean, simple, and effective.

Comment: Actually, this only checks that there are at *least* two digits and at *least* four letters. It works regardless, because you can't have anything more than 2 digits + 4 letters and come up with exactly six characters, but as far as explanations go... :)

Comment: a working regex fragment for validating exactly `x` digits and `y` letters would be like: `/^(?=([^0-9]*[0-9]){x}$)(?=([^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){y}$)/` but if you ask me the whole idea is excessively clever. If you *have* to do it to work with some tool that only accepts a regex for validation, okay. But if you don't need to do it, then say what you mean instead. :)

Comment: Suppose if i wanted it to match in the case of  'a1' or 'a11' or 'ab11' how would u put the range for [A-Za-z0-9]{6} if u make it [A-za-z0-9]{1,6} and for the assertion of the digits with (?=(.*[0-9]){1,2}) it still accepts 'a111'

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do it with only one regular expression, but you can certainly do it with two. That said it seems a bit excessive to be using regex for this task.

In Perl, I would do:

```
m/\d.*\d/ # match exactly 2 numeric characters
  &&
m/(?:[[:alpha:]].*){4}/ # match exactly 4 alpha characters
```

Comment: Very clever. You might also need checks for the length as well?

Comment: Your \d.*\d idea gave me inspiration for my own answer.  Thanks.  =]

Comment: Your matches aren't anchored, so again, they only check that *at least* two digits and four alphas exist somewhere in the string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think regex is the way to go here.

Sure, you could create an alternation of every possible allowed order of digits and letters, but you'd need 6 * 5 = 30 of them.

I don't know any way of doing the counting you want with regex.

You could have a regex to check you have 6 alpha-numeric characters, then do the counting manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
(?=[a-z]*\d?[a-z]*\d?)
(?![a-z]*\d[a-z]*\d[a-z]*\d)
(?=\d*[a-z]?\d*[a-z]?\d*[a-z]?\d*[a-z]?)
(?!\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z])
[\da-z]{2,6}
```

It works by making sure the selection has zero, one, or two digits (first lookahead), but doesn't have more than two (second lookahead).  Similarly, it checks for zero to four letters (third lookahead) but not more than four (fourth lookahead).  The fifth line matches one to six characters.

If you want to match words only, wrap it in `\b`.

EDIT: Now you added a requirement for the length of the match to be six characters.  Only a slight modification is needed:

```
(?=[a-z]*\d[a-z]*\d)
(?![a-z]*\d[a-z]*\d[a-z]*\d)
(?=\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z])
(?!\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z])
[\da-z]{6}
```

Comment: well, it should match these examples aBCd22 a2b2CD 22aBcD abcd22

Comment: @kurozakura: According to this site, mine do: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression should do it:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z]*$)(?=\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*$).*
```

Or more compact:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z]*(?:\d[a-zA-Z]*){2}$)(?=\d*(?:[a-zA-Z]\d*){4}$).*
```

Comment: Heh, that looks a lot like mine.  =]

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?<digit>\d)|(?<alpha>[a-zA-Z])){6}
(?<-alpha>){4}(?(alpha)(?!))
(?<-digit>){2}(?(digit)(?!))$
```

This will match 6 characters with exactly 2 digits and 4 letters. It does this by grabbing whatever it can then counting the results by popping them off the counter stack. Check [this](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups) link for more details.

- (?<-alpha>){4} means 'pop 4 matches off the stack'. If it cannot pop, it fails
- (?(alpha)(?!)) means 'if there is an alpha match, look for (?!), which always fails.
- ^ and $ match the beginning and ending